Installer integrity check has failed. - Cannot uninstall?
I'm trying to uninstall a software and I'm getting this error:

I've contacted the support but they are only responding with a very generic AI, no real help.
Can somebody please help me about how to remove this application?
I tried the usual way but don't know any other alternatives.
Thanks in advance.

If you reinstall the application are you able to uninstall the software?

No, it says I cannot install it even.

So download the installer again and make sure it isn't corrupt or incomplete, as that is mentioned in the error message.

@AdamVarhegyi - Delete the installer file you have. Download the installer from the developer's website.  Attempt to reinstall the software.  If that still does not work [edit] your question and provide the logs from the installer. Nullsoft Scriptable Install System (NSIS) is a third-party installer, the error you received, is only caused by a corrupt file associated with the installer.

@Ramhound Thank you Ramhound, I edited my question.

AdMob Sync is also a browser plugin. Try reinstalling AdMob Sync while in Safe Mode. AdMob can also be added to Java projects.  Be sure you have no Java applications running

One reason for such messages is that part of the app has already been removed manually. If that is the case, reinstall/repair AdMob Sync, then use Windows 10 Programs and Features to remove the app.
That said, some programs have defects in their uninstall app. If so, either:

Manually remove all the app's components from Program Files, Program Files (x86), ProgramData, C:\Users\ subfolders, and the Windows Registry.

Or

Use an application removal tool, such as Revo Uninstaller, Geek Uninstaller, Bulk Crap Uninstaller, etc.

